# How to print array after each pass in c for a bubblesort algorithm?

Tags: c, arrays, bubble-sort

I am using this bubblesort code I found online as a reference for this question (https://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-bubble-sort).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int array[100], n, c, d, swap;

  printf("Enter number of elements\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);

  for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);

  for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
  {
    for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
    {
      if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
      {
        swap       = array[d];
        array[d]   = array[d+1];
        array[d+1] = swap;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

  for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
     printf("%d\n", array[c]);

  return 0;
}
```

If I want it to print the array every time a swap is made, what changes should I make?

Comment: Add a printing function after(before?) each swap.

Comment: Write a function that prints all the elements of the array. Call it after `... array[d+1] = swap;` and before the `}`.

Comment: Working with sorting code can be a good learning exercise, but know this: (1) Bubble sort is among the worst of the sorting algorithms out there.  There's no reason to ever use it. (2) In fact (and, again, unless you're doing it for practice) in production code there's rarely a need to implement *any* sorting algorithm by hand: just call `qsort` and be done with it.

Comment: @SteveSummit Well, almost. Bubble sort *is* [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts) at least, unlike Quicksort. So its nice if you want to sort by multiple fields easily.

Comment: @jpaugh Sure, but (a) I believe there are plenty of stable sorts with decent performance, and (b) C library `qsort` is *not* necessarily Quicksort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a function to show all the elements of the array. Here is a fancy version:

```
void print_array(int *array, int size) {
    int i;
    putchar('{');    /* Make sure your array isn't empty or add a check */
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d%s", array[i], i + 1 == size ? "}" : ", ");
    }   /* The second argument is a ternary operator to put a ',' or a '}' */
}
```

Add it here :

```
for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
{
    for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
    {
        if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
        {
            swap       = array[d];
            array[d]   = array[d+1];
            array[d+1] = swap;
            print_array(array, 100);
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `putchar ('\n')` -- no need to call the variadic `printf` to output a single character -- that's what `putchar` is for...

Comment: That's right, thanks for noticing it, i edited my post.
However any optimizing compiler (ex: `gcc/clang -O3`) would do that for you.

Comment: Agreed regarding the optimizing compiler, but when answering questions on StatckOverflow, you step into the role of the teacher. You always want to convey the proper way of doing things.